# Where can the broken stasis pod be found?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

In which sectors can I find the broken stasis pod?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[According to this Wiki article](http://ftlwiki.com/wiki/Ships#Unidentified_Cruiser)

> Engi Homeworlds or Engi Controlled (Green), Pirate (Red), or Rock (Red) Controlled sectors at a distress beacon.

Comment: Thanks. Are they always at distress beacons, or only in Rock controlled sectors?

Comment: Well, that list clearly it (the event you get it from) can spawn in 3 additional types of sectors (2 Engi, 1 pirate).  As for the distress beacon, anecdotally yes.  From a few recent examples I got it at distress beacons.

Comment: Yes, it's always at a distress beacon.